# Compare two object arrays and find the indices

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays,
this is the first array:

```
 const users= [
  {
    id: '112',
    firstName: 'a',
    lastName: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: '118',
    firstName: 'c',
    lastName: 'd'
  },

  {
    id: '113',
    firstName: 'e',
    lastName: 'f'
  },

  {
    id: '115',
    firstName: 'g',
    lastName: 'h'
  },
  {
    id: '114',
    firstName: 'i',
    lastName: 'j'
  },
  {
    id: '1151',
    firstName: 'o',
    lastName: 'p'
  },
  {
    id: '1171',
    firstName: 'q',
    lastName: 'r'
  }
];
```

And this is the second one:

```
 const user2 = [
{
      id: '112',
      firstName: 'a',
      lastName: 'b'
},
      {
      id: '113',
      firstName: 'e',
      lastName: 'f'
    },
    {
      id: '114',
      firstName: 'i',
      lastName: 'j'
    },
]
```

What I want,
compare these two arrays based on value `id` and if `id` is equal in both arrays. I want to find indices for array `users` for that `id` which is equal in both arrays.
I tried to compare by `filter` method and tried `findIndex` but it is not working.

EDIT:

```
       const result = this.users.filter((obj1) => {
  return user2.some((obj2) => {
    return obj1.id=== obj2.id;          // unique id
  });
 });
```

I am not sure how to find indices.
expected output to return the indices of `users` array for that `id` which is equal in `user2` array

Comment: Please add the `filter` and `findIndex` code you've tried

Comment: Please write (Add) here what output  you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the `users` array to an object indexed by the user id:

```js
const users=[{id:'112',firstName:'a',lastName:'b'},{id:'118',firstName:'c',lastName:'d'},{id:'113',firstName:'e',lastName:'f'},{id:'115',firstName:'g',lastName:'h'},{id:'114',firstName:'i',lastName:'j'},{id:'1151',firstName:'o',lastName:'p'},{id:'1171',firstName:'q',lastName:'r'}];
const user2=[{id:'112',firstName:'a',lastName:'b'},{id:'113',firstName:'e',lastName:'f'},{id:'114',firstName:'i',lastName:'j'},{id:'500',firstName:'i',lastName:'s'},];

const reducedUsers = users.reduce((carry, item, index) => (carry[item.id] = {...item, index}, carry), {});

for (let user of user2) {
  const index = reducedUsers.hasOwnProperty(user.id) ? reducedUsers[user.id].index : -1;
  console.log(`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} has index ${index} in users`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const myUsers = users.filter(user => user2.filter(usr => usr.id === user.id).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `filter`:

```js
const users= [
  {
    id: '112',
    firstName: 'a',
    lastName: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: '118',
    firstName: 'c',
    lastName: 'd'
  },

  {
    id: '113',
    firstName: 'e',
    lastName: 'f'
  },

  {
    id: '115',
    firstName: 'g',
    lastName: 'h'
  },
  {
    id: '114',
    firstName: 'i',
    lastName: 'j'
  },
  {
    id: '1151',
    firstName: 'o',
    lastName: 'p'
  },
  {
    id: '1171',
    firstName: 'q',
    lastName: 'r'
  }
]; 

 const user2 = [
{
      id: '112',
      firstName: 'a',
      lastName: 'b'
},
      {
      id: '113',
      firstName: 'e',
      lastName: 'f'
    },
    {
      id: '114',
      firstName: 'i',
      lastName: 'j'
    },
]

function filterArrays(arr1, arr2){
  return arr1.map((el1) => {
     return arr2.filter((el2) => {
        return el2.id == el1.id;
     })
   }).filter((el) => el.length > 0);
 }
 
 console.log(filterArrays(users, user2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are interested to get the indexes from both arrays

```js
const users = [{
    id: '112',
    firstName: 'a',
    lastName: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: '118',
    firstName: 'c',
    lastName: 'd'
  },

  {
    id: '113',
    firstName: 'e',
    lastName: 'f'
  },

  {
    id: '115',
    firstName: 'g',
    lastName: 'h'
  },
  {
    id: '114',
    firstName: 'i',
    lastName: 'j'
  },
  {
    id: '1151',
    firstName: 'o',
    lastName: 'p'
  },
  {
    id: '1171',
    firstName: 'q',
    lastName: 'r'
  }
];

const user2 = [{
    id: '112',
    firstName: 'a',
    lastName: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: '113',
    firstName: 'e',
    lastName: 'f'
  },
  {
    id: '114',
    firstName: 'i',
    lastName: 'j'
  },
];

function filterArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
    const index = arr2.findIndex(y => x.id === y.id);

    if (index === -1) {
      return tmp;
    }

    tmp.push({
      userInfos: x,
      arrayIndex1: xi,
      arrayIndex2: index,
    });

    return tmp;
  }, []);
}

console.log(filterArrays(users, user2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure lodash's intersectionBy method should do the trick.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionBy

```
// The _.property iteratee shorthand.
_.intersectionBy([{ 'x': 1 }], [{ 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
// => [{ 'x': 1 }]
```

"This method is like _.intersection except that it accepts iteratee which is invoked for each element of each arrays to generate the criterion by which they're compared. The order and references of result values are determined by the first array. The iteratee is invoked with one argument:
(value)."

Answer (score 0):

```
    const user2 = [
{
      id: '112',
      firstName: 'a',
      lastName: 'b'
},
      {
      id: '113',
      firstName: 'e',
      lastName: 'f'
    },
    {
      id: '114',
      firstName: 'i',
      lastName: 'j'
    },
]

const users= [
  {
    id: '112',
    firstName: 'a',
    lastName: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: '118',
    firstName: 'c',
    lastName: 'd'
  },

  {
    id: '113',
    firstName: 'e',
    lastName: 'f'
  },

  {
    id: '115',
    firstName: 'g',
    lastName: 'h'
  },
  {
    id: '114',
    firstName: 'i',
    lastName: 'j'
  },
  {
    id: '1151',
    firstName: 'o',
    lastName: 'p'
  },
  {
    id: '1171',
    firstName: 'q',
    lastName: 'r'
  }
]; 

const user2Id = user2.map(user => user.id);

users.forEach((user,i) => {
  if (user2Id.indexOf(user.id) > 0) {
    console.log(user.id + " is present in user2 array at position " + user2Id.indexOf(user.id));
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` and do something like this:

```js
function findCommonIndices(array1, array2) {
    const tempSet = new Set();

    array1.forEach(arr => {
        tempSet.add(arr.id);
    });

    const foundIndices = [];

    array2.forEach((arr, index) => {
        if (tempSet.has(arr.id)) {
            foundIndices.push(index);
        }
    });

    return foundIndices;
}
```